# How to avoid "Too many open files" issue in load balancer, what are side effects of setting ulimit -n to a higher value?

Tags: amazon-ec2

When load balancing a production system with heavy load of requests, or while load testing it, we face a 'Too many open files' issue as below.

```
[2011-06-09 20:48:31,852]  WARN - HttpCoreNIOListener System may be unstable: IOReactor encountered a checked exception : Too many open files
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:113)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener$2.run(HttpCoreNIOListener.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This exception comes in load balancer, if the maximum allowed files  (ulimit) to be open is set to low.
we can fix the above exception by increasing the ulimit by giving a higher value (given 655350 here).
ulimit -n 655350

however setting ulimit -n to a higher number may affect overall performance of load balancer and hence response time of our website in unprecedented ways. Any known side effects od setting unumber -n to higher value?

Comment: you can use lsof command to see the current open files and find if there a deleted open files.

Answer (score 0):

The side effects will be exactly that - under normal circumstances you want to limit the number of open file handles for a process so it doesn't exhaust available file descriptors or do other bad stuff due to programming errors or DoS attacks.  If you're comfortable that your system won't do that (or plainly won't work within normal limits!) then there's no other side effects.